# android ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE not storing video

Tags: android, video, storage

Hi My following code records video. but it is not saved in the given path. how to get the stored video file path.I used data.getdata and it is not working.

```
String rootPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
            String filePath = rootPath + "/NewImage.3gp";

            File file = new File( filePath );
            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file );
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE );
            intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );
            intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, "1");

            startActivityForResult( intent, Constants.CAMERA_REQUEST );
```

Comment: What device and are there any errors?

Comment: No Errors. this code completely works for action image capture. This video is available in phone gallery.

Comment: More of explanation of what you **JUST** said, meaning we need to see what you're trying to do with the intent's data.

Comment: I am going to upload the video to amazons3, so need its stored path.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem? I'm also in same situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing wrong, just update your first line of question to below,

```
String rootPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```